# How can I compare elements from different indexes in struct

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct workspace {
    int ID;
    int price;
    int incoming_amount;
    int outgoing_amount;
    int date;
};

int main ()
{
    workspace works[5];
    string type_amount;
    int incoming_IDs[5];
    int incoming_IDs_counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> works[i].ID;
        cin >> works[i].price;
        cout << "What type of amount (inc/out)?" << endl;
        cin >> type_amount;
        if(type_amount == "inc"){
            incoming_IDs[incoming_IDs_counter] = works[i].ID;
            incoming_IDs_counter++;
            works[i].outgoing_amount = 0;
            cin >> works[i].incoming_amount;
        }
        else if(type_amount == "out"){
            works[i].incoming_amount = 0;
            cin >> works[i].outgoing_amount;
        }
        cin >> works[i].date;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code so far, now I have to check the following:

- Make sure the ID has an incoming amount added to it, before it can be an outgoing amount.
- Make sure the price for incoming amount if smaller than the outgoing amount.

So, I worked on the first one and I got this function:

```
bool INC_Exists(workspace &works, int &incoming_IDs_counter, int incoming_IDs[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < incoming_IDs_counter; i++){
        if(incoming_IDs[i] == works.ID){
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems to work and does the job, but for the second one, I don't know how to work it out. How can I efficiently check if the price of the outgoing amount if smaller than the incoming amount for the same ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool Valid_Price(workspace *works, int& incoming_IDs_counter, int incoming_IDs[], workspace &workz){
    bool valid_price;
    for(int j = 0; j < incoming_IDs_counter; j++){
        if(incoming_IDs[j] == workz.ID){
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                if(works[k].ID == workz.ID){
                    if(works[k].price < workz.price){
                        valid_price = true;
                    }
                    else if(works[k].price > workz.price){
                        valid_price = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return valid_price;
}
```

Tested and it seems to work..

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
bool INC_Exists(workspace &works, int &incoming_IDs_counter, int incoming_IDs[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < incoming_IDs_counter; i++){
        if(incoming_IDs[i] == works.sifra){
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

is invalid because structure workspace has no data member sifra,

If I have understood correctly the requirement

> •Make sure the ID has an incoming amount added to it, before it can be
>   an outgoing amount

you need to check whether object works is among elements of int incoming_IDs[]. The function could look the following way

```
bool INC_Exists( const int incoming_IDs[], int incoming_IDs_counter,  const workspace &works )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < incoming_IDs_counter && works.ID != incoming_IDs[ i ] ) i++; 

    return ( i != incoming_IDs_counter );
}
```

As for this condition

> •Make sure the price for incoming amount if smaller than the outgoing
>   amount

then it can be represented by expression

```
works.price < works. outgoing_amount
```

But I don't know where this condition has to be used. From your description it is totally unclear.

Comment: Fixed the sifra part in the last update. Now let me explain the second thing. When we input "works", we have declaration of types, incoming or outgoing, if it's incoming, then it has outgoing amount = 0. And the incoming amount has a specific price and outgoing amount as well. I need to check on input for outgoing amount, if the price is bigger than the price for incoming amount with the same ID. (incoming_amount.price < outgoing_amount.price for the same ID (they can't be inputted at the same time though, which causes a 'little' problem because they have different index))

Comment: The problem is that when you are entering outgoing amount the array can have no  element with incoming amount and the same ID. It can appear later (it it will appear). So I do not understand this requirement.

Comment: This is just an example code (80% of code is cut for easier understanding), so the first requirement is just because of that. After I implement the first, then I have to do the second one, which is my main problem.. I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool Valid_Price(workspace *works, int& incoming_IDs_counter, int incoming_IDs[], workspace &workz){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < incoming_IDs_counter; j++){
            if(incoming_IDs[j] == workz.ID){
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                    if(works[k].price < workz.price){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code for the second part.